# SQL Error Code: 1172 on update not insert

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have a very basic query here

```
UPDATE leads
SET created = NOW()
WHERE id IN(
    4142429,
    4142430,
    4142431,
    4142432,
    4142433,
    4142434,
    4142435,
    4142436,
    4142437
);
```

But whenever i try to run it in sqlYOG, I get the error:

```
Error Code: 1172
Result consisted of more than one row
```

I did some research to the error, and that turned up this question:

[Error 1172 : Result consisted more than one row (in SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820109/error-1172-result-consisted-more-than-one-row-in-sql)

which has already been answered, but the answer is not clear. I'm not inserting anything into the table either.

I have also tried doing the query

```
UPDATE leads SET created = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY WHERE ID = 4142432;
```

But I still get the same error.

Why does this happen when I am only updating one row?

Comment: What is the datatype of column `created`?

Comment: datatype is `datetime`

Comment: Did you try running the same query using MySQL terminal ? Or, is this query part of a larger query, which you are not showing here in the question ?

Comment: This is the entire query. All I want to do is update the created date. I do not have access to the MySQL terminal.

Comment: Your query looks fine and should work for both the scenarios that you tried. Just a thought, do you have any triggers on table like `TRIGGER AFTER INSERT` that might be causing this issue.

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: This link might be helpful for identifying triggers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363/how-do-you-list-all-triggers-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: Yeah, I have a lot, it's not my database. My colleague is experiencing the same error on their machine, so there must be a larger problem at play here.

Comment: Thanks for your help though.